# Line-endings in go-language source files using vim and git on MS-Windows

Tags: git, go, vim, file-format

#### The situation

I am writing go language applications on Windows 10. I use vim to edit my source files. I use git for version control.

The go language comes with some unusually rigid prescriptions for source file formatting. I have decided my life will be easier if I go along with this.

#### The problem

the `go fmt` command is useful for sorting imports, lining up columns and other things. I'm inclined to use it prior to checkin and at other times.

The `go fmt` command changes line endings to `lf`. This causes both **`git`** and **`vim`** to issue warnings.

#### My solution?

*Moved into an "Answer" after 3 months because no other answers appeared and it's probably better for other people with a similar problem to see in a search result that this question has 1 Answer rather than 0 Answers*

#### My question.

Is my line-ending solution optimal or have I missed something that may bite me later?

Comment: I think it's good. Not only for go, but disabling `core.autocrlf` is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My solution.

To eliminate the warnings I configured vim and git to work the way golang likes.

#### git

The following command stops git from trying to do what is normally the right thing: standard line-endings in repo, platform line-endings on each developers working directory, convert as needed.

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Now git won't change `lf` to `crlf` on checkout or bleat about line-endings.

#### vim

In `_vimrc`

```
au FileType go setl ts=3 sw=3 nowrap nu syntax=go ruler fileformat=unix
```

The `fileformat=unix` seems to keep vim complaint-free regarding line-endings that are not native to the platform.

---

#### Footnote

3 months after posting the above question I haven't come across any drawbacks or problems - at least not the way I use `go`, `vim` and `git`.